# How to change cube width on collision in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am making a mobile game using Unity3D and C#. I am trying to find a way to have a script that makes the cube health bar go down when it hits an obstacle with the tag 'Take Damage'. Is there an easy way for the bar to go down with a script?

Something using `onCollisionEnter` would be good.

Comment: Use a UI Slider and change it's value over code. I'm sure you'll find a tutorial if you search for healthbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLfNP4Sc_iA) on creating a health bar for beginners. But if you don't want to use the UI system:

```
class HealthBar
{
    int health = 100;
    int damage = 5;
    float toBarScale = 20f;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.scale = new Vector3(health / toBarScale, transform.scale.y, 0);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Take Damage")) return;
        health = Mathf.Clamp(health - damage, 0, 100);
        transform.scale = new Vector3(health / toBarScale, transform.scale.y, 0);
    }
}
```